# How is GetHashCode Implemented for Booleans?

Tags: c#, boolean, gethashcode

I was wondering how exactly they generate a hashcode from boolean types in C#/.NET?

Comment: Simple. If the value is `true`, hashcode is 1, if the value is `false`, hashcode is 0.

Comment: @Dennis_E So something like : "return bool ? 1 : 0;"

Comment: Exactly. But in the source, the 1 and 0 are defined as constants. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,b7e0da11f526e363,references

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the actual source code for .NET [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,b7e0da11f526e363), the implmentation for `GetHashCode()` for a bool is

```
  private bool m_value;

  internal const int True = 1; 
  internal const int False = 0; 

  public override int GetHashCode() {
      return (m_value)?True:False;
  }
```

(And yes, it is weird that `System.Boolean` contains a `bool` as a member variable, when the class is compiled the CLR treats the "primitive" types `Boolean`, `Byte`, `SByte`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Int32`, `UInt32`, `Int64`, `UInt64`, `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr`, `Char`, `Double`, and `Single` special so they can do stuff like that)